# NPE при восстановлении элемента ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Удаление элемента происходит нормально, но при восстановлении его на то же место в `ArrayList` выдает:

> Null Pointer Exception Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

```
tasks.remove(taskPosition);
Log.d("TASK", "Task has been deleted");
Snackbar.make(getView(), "Task has been deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("Cancel", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tasks.add(taskPosition, tempTask);
            Log.d("TASKS", "Task deletion has been canceled");
        }
    }).show();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Вы удалили `tempTask` из `ArrayList` а потом пытаетесь его добавить, но он `null`. Кстати, вы забыли вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged` после добавления таски.

Comment: Что-то я в упор не вижу вызова `toString()`, Вы уверены, что ошибка в этом куске?